# Some jquery scripts work in IE Edge, but do not work on other versions of IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Some jquery scripts work in IE Edge, but do not work on other versions of IE.

```
$(".facts").viewportChecker({
    callbackFunction: function() {
        $(".fact-to").countTo({
            speed: 500,
            refreshInterval: 2,
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Lots of things don't work on IE. This particular plugin might just not support IE

Comment: Note: a trailing comma after the last key-value pair (`refreshInterval: 2`) in an object initializer used to be considered a syntax error. Depending on the version of IE you're targeting and the document mode its using, the comma may still be considered invalid.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? Can you include a sample of the related markup? Are any errors being reported? If so, what are they reporting? What version of jQuery are you using? What version of a IE are you using? Do the jQuery plugins you're using state in their documentation anything about browser support? If so, do they mention that version of IE as being supported?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it did not solve my problem. In console no errors. I use jquery 2.1.4 and ie 11, 10 and 9. The plugin supports ie and usage examples of the plugin working in IE http://dirkgroenen.nl/jQuery-viewport-checker/

Comment: I tried to change version of jquery to 1.8.0 or 1.9.0 it didn't solve the problem

Comment: ups sorry. it doesn't work in ie. Thank you.